# Best practice for users to scp .war files to tomcat /webapps folder?

Tags: permissions, tomcat

I have a tomcat 8 installation on an ubuntu 14 server.

I want to give write access to the /opt/tomcat/webapps folder to a few users so they can scp .war files directly there from their local machines.

Is there any best practice for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're working with developers, setup a Jenkins to build their source codes, and setup jenkins to handle the deployment.

Jenkins can work with shell so you can use `scp`, so you can control permission of jenkins without granting any permission for developers to server.

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277223/jenkins-auto-deploy-tomcat-7

Comment: Ah yeah this is for non-developers.

Comment: The same, just dont let them touch your server